# Eigen values of a certain type of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a $N \times N$ hermitian matrix $A$. Consider a complex $N \times 1$ vector $b$ and positive constant $c$. Given $A$ (hence its eigen-values), can we find the eigen-values of the following matrix. 
\begin{align}
B=\begin{bmatrix}
A & b \\
b' & c
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

in terms of those of $A$ (or $A$'s entries) and, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: I think that you should add a question mark after "the matrix"

Comment: @Belgi ok, I will do that

Comment: What kind of characterization are you looking for? I don't believe there's a simple representation, otherwise this would be a really good way of computing eigenvalues! You can, however, say the sum of eigenvalues of B is the sum of eigenvalues of A plus c.

Comment: I figured out that it isn't easy as it looks like later!!. And yes, your observation is really true. If it was true, one could start from a $2\times 2$ and thus find all the eigen-values of any $N\times N$ matrix :) , too good to be true!

Comment: @Stuart As the OP has approved your answer, please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).